# Javascript getElement field not working outside of google chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, parent

I wrote some code that works well on chrome. However, when running it on firefox it doesn't work. Firebug reports that the parentElement field in the getClass function, is not defined. It seems that maybe firefox wants another way to access the field like getParentElement or something. Does anyone have any other ideas that I could try?

```
function drawTile() {

    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var newDivClass = document.createElement('div');
    newDivClass.setAttribute("class", "menu");
    var newul = document.createElement('ul');

    var tab1 = document.createElement('li');
    tab1.innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="getClass(this, 1);"> Tile </a>';

    newul.appendChild(tab1);
    newDivClass.appendChild(newul);
    newdiv.appendChild(newDivClass);

    var contentdiv2 = document.createElement('div');
    contentdiv2.setAttribute("id", "tabcontent2");
    contentdiv2.innerHTML = 'Data Manipulation Options';

    newdiv.appendChild(contentdiv2);
    rootTile.parent.appendChild(newdiv);
    //getClass(tab2.firstChild, 1); //Sets the tile to an initial state
}

function getClass(tile, selected) {
    var class = tile.parentElement.parentElement;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.parentNode) instead! [`parentElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534327%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) isn't part of any standard, it's a MS invention that WebKit copied (and so it works in Chrome)

Comment: hahah thanks! Where could I find tutorials that explain standards?

Comment: You find the standards from the World Wide Web Consortium, http://www.w3.org/, for tutorials, you can just Google Search, many sources online.

Comment: @Steve - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/web is the best resource. If you use google always add `mdc` to your search term. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

it should be `element.parentNode` i think